# how to sync leds with the beat?

Tags: led, amplifier, speakers, led-strip

how do i make led strip flash with the beat (subwoofer) without risking burning them out and im using a car amplifier that kicks out 1250w peak for the subwoofer i tried using a multimeter i got around 45v and a current around 5A from the amp i tried using a npn transistor but it went so hot that i burned my finger and the current coming out from the amp breaked through the base into the emitter into the leds and bruning them out whats your recommendations ?[image: here is what i tried to do with the transistor]

Comment: Instead of trying to look at the output of the power amp, why not use the line-level signal input? Buffer the input signal, rectify it, throw it through a peak detector, and run that to your LEDs.

Answer (score 1):

This circuit practically shorts the amp's output through the base-emitter junction (less the junction and diode voltage drops).  If you want to use a bipolar transistor, a resistor could be used to limit the base current and emitter/LED current...

Is your amp DC-coupled?  Can your transistor handle a 40v Vbe?  Those could have contributed to the overheating...

Comment: Vbe is rated 4v and my amp is on low pass filter do you have any  recommendation on a transistor i can use or a different method